# Style bugs with new version of chrome 84.0.4147.105

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, version, margin

For chrome version 84.0.4147.105 =>

- Element goes up in flex container if i setup for container `display: block` works fine.

This is style for container =>

```css
    position: absolute;
    left: 1254.57px;
    top: 114.8px;
    width: 179.707px;
    height: 378px;
    background: url(assets/images/test.png) 0% 0% / 100% 10% no-repeat rgb(35, 68, 43);
    padding-top: 43.2px;
    font-family: helveti5;
    font-size: 2.3vmin;
    overflow: scroll;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    text-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 5px 3px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
```

My style element inside container =>

```html
<div id="123" style="display: inline-table;width:97%;" class="t123"><p style="width:100%;height:6%;
                                  color: #ffffff;
                                  background: #1c2d20;
                                  text-shadow: 0px 5px 3px #000000;
                                  margin: 0;
                                  padding-top: 2.7%;
                                  line-height: 2;
                                  margin-bottom: 0;
                                  text-decoration: none;
                                  ">SOMETHING</p> <p style="width:100%;height:6%;margin-bottom:0;"></p> <p mark="Red" evwin="10" style="padding:4px 2px 4px;height:6%;flex:1;font-size: 1.85vmin;border:solid #71c940 1px;min-width:43%;
                           margin-bottom: 1px;
                           color: white;
                           background: #ff2614;">Red (2) </p><p style="background:#1c2d20;width:100%;height:6%;margin-top:5%;margin-bottom:5%;color:white;"> something </p><p style="background:#1c2d20;width:100%;height:6%;margin-top:5%;margin-bottom:5%;color:white;"> SOmething </p></div>
```

Any suggestion for fix without exceptions , detect browser ver etc ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with this Chrome version and for me the solution was to remove min-height in the child element.

Other variant is to switch style.display from `flex` to `block` for parent.